# How to change NavigationView header background programmatically?

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I want to change NavigationView header background programmatically but got something that not I want.

this is MainActivity I attempt to change Navigation header background in this way:

```
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
            tv_nav_header = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.text_nav_header);
            tv_nav_header.setText(username);
            tv_nav_header.setBackground(drawable);
```

this is my nav_header.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp">
        <cn.xyz.util.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_nav_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:text="tempLocalUser"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="100" />
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

the actual show like this,this isn't my want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqypF.png)

and below is my want,this is imple by nav_header.xml RelativeLayout attr

android:background="@color/colorPrimary_blue"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRJIr.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the background color to the TextView. Instead try setting the color on the RelativeLayout. Try the following -

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
header.setBackground(drawable);
tv_nav_header = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.text_nav_header);
tv_nav_header.setText(username);
tv_nav_header.setBackground(drawable);
```